# Lightweight alternative to socket.io for transport only

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is there a lightweight alternative to socket.io for transport only?

I have an node.js application that uses socket.io simply as an message transport. My application is managing sessions and message routing on its own, I am simply using socket.io for transport -- websocket + whatever the default fallback is for older browsers.

The newer version of socket.io seems to get heavier and heavier, now comes with redis support, which I totally do not need.

Comment: +1, but if you are looking for something to fallback to something other than websockets for transport, you are using the bulk of Socket.IO, and I don't think you are going to find something lighter that meets that need.

Comment: Come to think of it, my app is targetting mobile on the client side, so I don't really need fallback. I can probably implement fallback on my own if I need it down the road.

Comment: I use [PieSocket Channels](https://piesocket.com)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) module is amazingly fast (look at the [benchmarks](http://websockets.github.io/ws/benchmarks.html)), well tested, very very very lightweight, but with no you would have to do the fall-backs yourself, plus, it doesn't have an event emitter on top of it. But it's amazing at transporting only, if that's what you want. If you want a poor man's "session", just attach something to the ws object, like this:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer( /* some config */);
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function (message) {
        try {
            var obj = JSON.parse(message) // using JSON  over the conversation
        } catch (err) {
            var obj = {};
            console.log('probably not valid json');
        }
        switch (true) {
            case obj.name !== undefined:
                ws.name = obj.name; // Here's the poor man's session variable
                ws.send('Hello '+ws.name);
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Now the only thing missing would be an event emitter on top of it...

Comment: I am trying "ws" now. "ws" is actually what socket.io use under the hood. The downside is that I need to implement my own fallback. However, given that my application is designed around WebSocket-like communication, I'd rather gain the fine grain control.

Comment: Same with me. And in one or two years nearly more than 95% of the web browsers will be supporting web sockets.

Comment: Right now, it seems the biggest problem for websockets is the corporate firewalls (transparent reverse proxies on port 80/443). :-/

Comment: I found that if you go over port 443, even if not using SSL, the firewalls won't get in the way

Comment: Check out [ws-wrapper](https://github.com/bminer/ws-wrapper) if you need a lib to wrap a native WebSocket and give you an event-emitter API.

Comment: Thing that missed - is ``wse`` package :3

Answer (score 9):

There are other alternatives. `faye` - http://faye.jcoglan.com/ is one of them. Its similar to socket.io but uses `Bayeux` protocol. The other one if you prefer not to run a server - `pusher` - http://pusher.com/ .

Comment: And then there's always Ably as well https://www.ably.io, like Pusher, but with a focus on providing a robust pub/sub streaming API for developers with protocol interoperability and data integrity. 
__Note: I am the co-founder, but believe this is still a useful comment__

Comment: And if Pusher and Ably both are too expensive for you, try [PieSocket](https://piesocket.com).

We have been using it on all our systems.

Answer (score 6):

Look at [sock.js](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) - it tries to implement cross-browser websockets api and nothing more.

Answer (score 5):

For Node.js, you can try [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) + [ws-wrapper](https://github.com/bminer/ws-wrapper) + [ws-server-wrapper](https://github.com/bminer/ws-server-wrapper).  ws-wrapper is a lightweight lib that adds some event-handler functionality to WebSockets... similar to what you might find in socket.io.  In addition, you get Promise-based requests and namespacing.

As mentioned by others, the [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) module is very fast, lightweight, and even used by socket.io under the hood.  Native WebSockets are now [supported by all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets), so it seems silly to support other transports for most real-time web applications.

`ws-wrapper` doesn't even implement auto-reconnect, so if you want that, check out [this wiki page describing an exponential back-off approach](https://github.com/bminer/ws-wrapper/wiki/Client-side-Auto-Reconnect)

Finally, ws-server-wrapper is the library for the server side, allowing you to do things like: send a message to all connected WebSockets, listen for events from all WebSockets, etc.

Disclaimer: I am the author of ws-wrapper.  :)